# permutations algorithm

Tags: c++, vector, permutation

This is for a class so please don't be too specific, but I am looking for a way to list all permutations of an array of digits.

We have to arrange different numbers on different pillars (like a lock) to unlock a combination. There may be 6 numbers on each of the 4 pillars. But it should work for any n on r as long as n>r.

I have the way to randomly generate a combination, and methodically look for it in a list but I am having trouble producing an algorithm to generate all permutations.

I am able to get all combinations for digits 1-6 using this in C++:

```
//n = number of digits - 1; list = list of digits to work with; 
//number=finalized list of digits
void permute(int n, vector<int> list, vector<vector<int>>* number)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        number->push_back(list);

    }else
    {
        for(int i = 1;i<n;i++)
        {
            permute(n-1,list, number);
            if(n%2 == 0)
            {
                swap(list[1],list[n]);
            }else
            {
                swap(list[i],list[n]);
            }
        }
    }

};
```

But then i get a list such as
123456
163452
etc where 1 is always the first digit
but I need to also obtain when the first digit is switched around and only 4 digits are present.

example

6341

4163

etc where there are 4 digits that range from 1-6 and you have all possible combinations.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for another algorithm to supplement this or so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::next\_permutation Implementation Explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483060/stdnext-permutation-implementation-explanation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of All, let's talk your question to print all the **P(6,4)** array in set {1,2,3,4,5,6}, but std::next_permutation will only adapt for the permutation of all the element (**P(6,6)**), not suitable for your issue (**P(6,4)**).
I think use std::next_permutation can get the combination very easily, and since we know  `P(6,4)=C(6,4)*P(4,4)`, the simple code implementation maybe like this:

```
 1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <vector>
  3
  4 int main()
  5 {
  6     std::vector<int> list;
  7     std::vector<int> subList;
  8     std::vector<bool> flag;
  9
 10     for (int i=1; i<=6; ++i)
 11         list.push_back(i);
 12     flag.insert(flag.end(),4,1);
 13     flag.insert(flag.end(),2,0);
 14     std::sort(flag.begin(), flag.end());
 15     do
 16     {
 17         subList.clear();
 18         for(int i=0; i<flag.size(); ++i)
 19         {
 20             if(flag[i])
 21             {
 22                 subList.push_back(list[i]);
 23             }
 24         }
 25         do
 26         {
 27             for(std::vector<int>::iterator it=subList.begin(); it!=subList.end(); ++it)
 28             {
 29                 std::cout << *it << " ";
 30             }
 31             std::cout << std::endl;
 32         }while(std::next_permutation(subList.begin(), subList.end()));
 33         std::cout << std::endl;
 34     } while(std::next_permutation(flag.begin(), flag.end()));
 35     return 0;
 36 }
```

That's obviously the out loop look for **C(6,4)**, and the inner loop look for **P(4,4)**.
Didn't take much time on your code, for combination, you can use search method just like **DFS**, refer: [combinations of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078653/combinations-of)

Comment: Thanks! That's a very cool use of bools; never seen that before. Helped me understand it a bunch!

Answer (score 8):

C++ offers a perfect solution for this - it's [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) (you need to include `<algorithms>` to use it).

```
vector<int> list;
std::sort(list.begin(), list.end());
do {
    // use the current permutation of the list
} while (std::next_permutation(list.begin(), list.end()));
```

An important point to remember about this function is that if you would like to go through *all* permutations of a range, the range must be sorted before you make the first call to `next_permuration`, otherwise you are going to stop before exhausting all permutations.

Comment: Great response! Also note that the library is called `<algorithm>` and not `<algorithms>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to implement your own, this may be no help, but C++ has `next_permutation` built-in.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/

The algorithm behind this function is explained here: [std::next_permutation Implementation Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483060/stdnext-permutation-implementation-explanation)

Answer (score 1):

A general algorithm for recursively generating permutations of N-length from a list of N items is:

For each element x in list

Make a copy of list without element x; call it newList
Find all of the permutations of newList (thats the recursion, btw)

Add element x to the beginning of each permutation of newList

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

typedef std::list<int> IntList;
void iterlist(IntList& lst)
{
    for (IntList::iterator it=lst.begin(); it!=lst.end(); it++)
        cout << " " << *it;
    cout << endl;
}

std::list<IntList> permute(IntList& L1)
{
    if (L1.size() == 1)
        return std::list<IntList>(1,L1);

    std::list<IntList> res;
    for (IntList::iterator i = L1.begin(); i != L1.end();)
    {
        // remember this
        int x = (*i);

        // make a list without the current element
        IntList tmp(L1.begin(), i++);
        tmp.insert(tmp.end(), i, L1.end());

        // recurse to get all sub-permutations
        std::list<IntList> sub = permute(tmp);

        // amend sub-permutations by adding the element
        for (std::list<IntList>::iterator j=sub.begin(); j!=sub.end();j++)
            (*j).push_front(x);

        // finally append modified results to our running collection.
        res.insert(res.begin(), sub.begin(), sub.end());
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    IntList lst;
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        lst.push_back(i);
    std::list<IntList> res = permute(lst);
    for (std::list<IntList>::iterator i=res.begin(); i!=res.end(); i++)
        iterlist(*i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I like the way you did it! Helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This function lists all permutations using bitset

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

const int N = 3;

void permute(string_view s, bitset<N> &mask, string &pref)
{
    if (mask.all()) {
        cout << pref << endl;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (!mask[i]) {
            mask.set(i);
            pref.push_back(s[i]);
            permute(s, mask, pref);
            pref.pop_back();
            mask.reset(i);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string pref;
    bitset<N> mask;
    permute(string("abc"), mask, pref);
    return 0;
}
```

and with a few modifications, it prints all combinations

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

const int N = 3;
const int M = 2;

void permute(string_view s, bitset<N> &mask, string &pref)
{
    if (pref.size() == M) {
        cout << pref << endl;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (!mask[i]) {
            mask.set(i);
            permute(s, mask, pref);
            pref.push_back(s[i]);
            permute(s, mask, pref);
            pref.pop_back();
            mask.reset(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string pref;
    bitset<N> mask;
    permute(string("abc"), mask, pref);
    return 0;
}
```